# Self-referencing topological execution order in svelte

Tags: svelte

In svelte, how does the reactive block topological execution order work with self-referencing blocks (/blocks that alter the reactive variable that they refer to)?

For example if I do this:

```js
<script>
export let a = [];
export let b = [];

// Merge produces a sorted array, assuming that a and b are sorted
import { merge } from './utils.js';

$: combined = merge(a,b);
$: a = [...a].sort();
$: b = [...b].sort();

</script>

{#each combined as item}
<p>{item}</p>
{/each}
```

Are `a` and `b` guaranteed to be sorted before they are combined? It seems to be working as expected. What's the rule? Is this documented somewhere?

A more complete example with interactive UI: https://svelte.dev/repl/24135c927ca14186b1884c47a851e471?version=3.23.2

**EDIT:** changed declaration order to make the behaviour clearer

Comment: The only thing somewhat related I've been able to find is [this](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/2386). But it doesn't say anything about order of execution with respect to other reactive blocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Svelte analyzes the reactive statements and sorts them, if needed. It has to do that, because some can depend on more then one variables, that are reactive, and it has to ensure, the all are updated correctly.

I've updated your REPL a bit so that we can spy on the generated `$$self.$$.update` method: https://svelte.dev/repl/28ad4789488f449f903e1165c1134e54?version=3.23.2

I've added some code (which should NEVER EVER be used in production as it messes around with svelte internals) to add a log statement to the updated method:

```
    onMount(() => {
        // get the component
        const self = eval('$$self');
    
        // store the update method
        const update = self.$$.update
        
        // replace the update method with one that logs some informatin and calls the original one
    self.$$.update = () => {
        console.log('update called, dirty=', self.$$.dirty) 
      update()
    }
    })
```

and add a click button, because otherwise svelte calculated everything before our update was in place.

What we see now is this:

```
"sorted b"
"sorted a"
"combined"
"update called, dirty="
▶
 Array(1)[ 6 ]
"sorted b"
"sorted a"
"combined"
```

1. svelte mounts the component with `a` and `b` as empty arrays
2. Then we click the button (our update is now monkey-patched and ready)
3. update is called once with a dirty value of 6, which is 2 + 4 and means, that `a` (2) and `b` (4) are dirty now. We did that with the button click
4. svelte runs the update method again

```
    $$self.$$.update = () => {
        if ($$self.$$.dirty & /*b*/ 4) {
            $: {
                $$invalidate(2, b = [...b].sort());
                console.log("sorted b");
            }
        }

        if ($$self.$$.dirty & /*a*/ 2) {
            $: {
                $$invalidate(1, a = [...a].sort());
                console.log("sorted a");
            }
        }

        if ($$self.$$.dirty & /*a, b*/ 6) {
            $: {
                $$invalidate(0, combined = merge(a, b));
                console.log("combined");
            }
        }
    };
```

Svelte recognized, that the reactive statement with the `merge` depends both on `a` and `b` and sorted the list of conditions so that it runs *after* the updated for `a` and `b`. The order of a and b doesn't matter, they don't depend on each other.

So, as a conclusion: yes, svelte guarantees that the merge is done on sorted lists (in this example) by compiling a correct update method and the order in which we declare the reactive statements, doesn't matter.

At least not for svelte. It does for readability, of course.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that the behaviour seems independent of declaration order (almost). The `combined` block always comes after `a` and `b` (`a` and `b` *sometimes* follow declaration order). See: https://svelte.dev/repl/4e77954ba64040519ac37f77bad916e0?version=3.23.2

Comment: I rewrote my answer, now that I understand how svelte does the updates :)